# wxHtmlWindow::SetPage() crash application when called second time

Tags: wxwidgets, windows-7-x64, wxhtmlwindow

I need to refresh html in `wxHtmlWindow` sometimes. But when I set `html` for the second time - my apllication crashed without any error.

code is [here](http://pastebin.com/s1SadjZ3)

What is this and how to avoid crashing?

**EDIT:** After some experimenting i found that code work well

```
void MessagesViewer::ShowMessages()
{
    wxString html2 = "TEST";
    m_pHtml->SetPage(thml2);
  //this->Show(true);
}
```

But when i uncomment line with Show - app starts crashing on 2d time I call this function.

Comment: Code: http://pastebin.com/s1SadjZ3

Comment: Whenever you get a crash you must look at the stack trace to understand where it is coming from. Also, try reproducing it in (known good) sample, e.g. `samples/html/about`. The problem is almost certainly not in the code you show.

Comment: I have Functions: ??() ??() ??() in stack trace =(

Comment: stupid me, I'm trying to debug release binary

Comment: Ok, i got stack trace - http://pastebin.com/u0dxUWwz and error - SEGFAULT. Error on the line with SetPage() call. It says nothing new to me. BTW, samples/html/about working well

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace shows that `m_pHtml` pointer is invalid. It's impossible to say why exactly does it happen from the code you show here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pNmAwuLk There is the code of class and client code function.

Comment: Can you open the secret to me, how you point out that m_pHtml invalid from stacktrace? I came from web, and such rich debug tools looks confusing to me

Comment: The program crashes when calling a method on this object, without even entering into it -- hence the object itself is invalid.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/VRmBymmIev7Xy There is the simplest app just to test this behavior. Maybe it's a bug in wxWidgets code?

Comment: If you think it's a bug in wxWidgets (which seems unlikely to me in this particular case), please try reproducing it in one of the wxHTML samples, e.g. `samples/html/about` with minimal changes. If you can do it, please [open a ticket](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/wiki/HowToSubmitTicket) with the patch reproducing the problem.